# make: *** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop. Stellar-core

Tags: c++, stellar, make, c

I followed the instructions on how to install the stellar core but when I ran `make install`, I got this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
```

I  configured it and everything worked out fine until this point. I'm using Fedora to run this operation.
I have a `Makefile.am` and a `Makefile.in` in the folder.